# How to prevent google showing my website images for specific keyword?

Tags: seo, google-image-search

i created a CMS site with admin panel (ex: ABC.com). few monthes ago i created another site (ex: XYZ.com) for another new client using that **same CMS admin panel** which i created for previous site.

but now my new client (xyz.com) complaining that when they search their website name on google images it shows images from other site (abc.com) as well. (2-3 images)

Are their any method i can prevent appearing images like this on google. means i just only want to stop google to display images from "abc.com" when people search as "xyz".

i have checked that "xyz" is not containing the keyword "abc". this is a puzzle for me that what is the fact google use to find a relevance between tow sites.
i searched about this every where ( even in stack ) but found nothing use-full.
if any one have had this experience please explain me. thanks.

note: both sites are being managed by same webmaster tool account.  XYZ

Answer (score 0):

If you copied abc.com to create xyz.com, may be xyz.com is pointing at images stored at abc.com. If so, the solution is to remove those references in xyz.com.

If you have deleted abc.com, it may take some time for Google to remove all the page of abc.com from the index. In Goggle Webmaster Tools, there is a possibility to remove a site (i.e. abc.com) from search result (I mean wipe it out in a couple of hours).